# which is better practice for python in this case ?iterator inside function or outside function

Tags: python, function, loops, performance

If i mention the word 'state machine' , most  people would go for state machine design. So i'd like to simplify the case to focus on the point.

Suggested here is a text flow, it's very long or it's frequently brought to current stage.

Each time I process a single character from the sequence and decide what the next state is. Here are two solutions:

```
textflow = iter(text)
endFlag = False
while True:
   process()
   if endFlag:break
```

then the process method would be like this

```
def process0():
    for x in textflow:
        do something
        if condition1:
           process = process1
           break
        elif cond2:
           process = process2
           break


def process1():
    for x in textflow:
        do something
        if cond0:
           process = process0
           break
        elif cond2:
           process = process2
           break
    ...
```

or

```
for x in text:
   process(x)
```

then the process method would be like this

```
def process0(x):
    do something
    if cond1:
      process = process1
    elif cond2:
      process = process2

def process1(x):
    do something
    if cond0:
       process = process0
    elif cond2:
       process = process2
....
```

In the first solution, each process method does the iteration by its own way and ends the process until the state is changed. In the second, the main loop does the iterations and each time process would be called.(`map()` could be use, but since the process would be changed everytime, it doesn't help.)

The state change would be like this:

```
0 1 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 ....
```

or like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 ...many 0 .. 0 1 ...many 1 ... 1 2......2 1 ..... 1
```

A more common case would be:

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 1 1 1 1 2 0 2 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 0 ....
```

I need an advisor to tell me which solution is more efficient.

Comment: Do you mean `process(textflow)` in your first example? Or is it `process` getting it from the surrounding scope?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what we're supposed to look at for optimization. There's the same number of function calls in each of your versions, the only difference is that one reads values from global variables and the other gets one of the variables passed in as a parameter. They both alter the global variable `process` so that's no different. I suspect the running time will be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will mostly depend on how many items you want to process, as function calls are expensive. If you have a large number of items, then embedding the loop inside the function is the better option. If it'll only iterate over a few items, I usually go with whichever is clearest in expressing intent.

Comment: a few is how much? 100 or 1000?it doesn't change every time,but it neither last very long for one state.

Comment: I would say "a large number of items" would start at a million. Maybe 100,000 if a given item requires more than minimal work. However, the general rule is to write it as clearly as possible first, then profile it and fix the slow parts. Don't optimize before you know what's actually slowing you down.